# fullpage.js position slide navigation position to bottom center

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullpage.js

I am having an issue with setting the position for slide navigation to the bottom centre of the page. Currently, it is set to bottom left of the page in my setup (http://enroute.evokeuprojects.com/bread-products.php).

In the fullpage.js examples, I have seen the position of the slide navigation is set to the centre but in my setup, it is not. I am using the paid extension that styles the navigation and not sure if using this extension has forced the position to the left as opposed to the center. I have tried the below code but the position still does not move

```
.fp-slidesNav {
    left: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}
```

Can anyone please help in guilding me to find a solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about the up-down arrows? Or the bullet navigation?

Comment: Hi Anurag, I am talking about the bullet navigation.

Comment: Find the div with those classes col-md-8 main-nav-wrap and set display: flex, justify-content:center